# Is this grounds for post deletion?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Is a post stating that an image is in a in-universe picture book but not providing a screenshot to prove it considered a bad quality post - specifically, bad enough that it's **grounds for deletion**?

(To be specific, the question for that answer is merely "does item X exist" with no elaboration asked for, so existence of an image in a book is enough to answer the question affirmatively with no elaboration.)

If the answer is "yes", why does a post stating "something exists in a film" not grounds for deletion - absent screenshot or a video to prove that (I'm assuming the site policy is that it isn't grounds for deletion, as the site is choke full of those kinds of answer).

<sub>P.S. To address a comment: I'm very specifically asking about **deletion, not downvoting**. I can easily see why someone would downvote such a post - everyone's standars of what is good/bad enough for votes differ.</sub>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that its wrong that this answer got deleted. It’s very common for us to answer questions, and then mention, will update with quotes later. This is essentially what DVK did, he answered the question, explained where the answer was, and then noted that he would flesh the answer out shortly when he gets back on his better PC. At most this deserved down votes, for not being a "great" answer.

DVK, answered the question:

> yes

Provided the source:

> Visual Dictionary explicitly shows it on Rey’s page

And then stated that he couldn’t post a picture at the moment but it was forthcoming.

Many answers for questions like Harry Potter start out like this.

> The answer is blah, blah, blah, because Dumbledore says so. (will add
>   quotes shortly)

Then the author proceeds to update with quotes later.

Obviously if someone else comes along and answers it completely with quotes and pictures first, the site is set up so we can upvote that answer, and downvote the “incomplete” answer.

Comment: Exactly. I can understand why this was closed, I just don't think it was appropriate.

Answer (score 12):

Relating specifically to the answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112871/20774):

### Should this answer have been deleted?

**No. Absolutely not.** It was on-topic, contained an answer to the question asked and objectively referenced a source.

### Should this answer have been downvoted to hell?

**Yes. Absolutely it should.** It was terse, contained no verifiable reference (such as transcribed text) and didn't explicitly state what it was that the source mentioned *actually referred to*.

---

Answer (score 5):

### No. Absolutely not. No.

An answer that contains an objective reference (e.g. that merely mentions a source) should not be deleted simply because it doesn't offer a link/picture/quote from that source.

If you were to say ...

> "I remember reading in an article in Time Magazine that George Lucas
>   planned for Luke to be Han's son"

... but didn't link to the article or offer anything more to back it up, then that's certainly grounds for the answer to be downvoted [for not being a good answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), but I see no objective grounds for the answer to be marked for deletion.